# Django - getting objects by field value (model is unknown)

Tags: python, django, object, generics, django-queryset

I'm trying to a view in Django that creates an object which contains a generic foreign key, and I want to write it in a way that would allow me to create it without specifying the type of the object for that generic FK, just the ID of the object.

For instance if I have this:

```
class Foo1 (models.Model):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(unique=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    ...

class Foo2 (models.Model):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(unique=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    ...

class Foo3 (models.Model):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(unique=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    ...

class Bar (models.Model):
    foo_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, related_name="content_type")
    foo_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    foo_object = GenericForeignKey('foo_type', 'foo_id')...
```

I would like to be able to get an object that belongs to any of the Foos by providing just the UUID (which should be unique throughout the DB).

I guess something that would look like this:

```
GenericFoo.objects.get(uuid=uuid)
```

Is this at all possible in Django?

Do point that I don't have any inheritance/abstract model implementation going on between the Foos at the moment because they are not related.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't belive you can fetch an object from an SQL database, without searching each table it might be in.

However you can write a method in Django that does this for you:

```
def get_by_uuid(uuid):
    for Model in [Foo1, Foo2, Foo3]:
        try:
            return Model.objects.get(uuid=uuid)
        except Model.DoesNotExist:
            pass
    return None  # Maybe you want to raise an exception here instead
```

Note that the database will not ensure that uuids are unique across all tables, although if you use `uuid.uuid4()` to generate them, you shouldn't get any collisions.

If you don't want to hardcode the list of models, you could introspect your [applications](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/applications/#module-django.apps)